# Interface Builder row height with self-sizing cells

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

When designing a table view cell that is self-sizing (e.g. using estimatedRowHeight and UITableViewAutomaticDimension), what to you enter in "Row Height" for the Table View Cell in Interface Builder?

The whole point of UITableViewAutomaticDimension is that I don't know the row height beforehand, so there should be a setting like "Calculate from current views and Autolayout configuration" in IB.

I mean, IB has all the intrinsic sizes and we can even specify placeholder heights, so it should be able to determine the (automatic) row height for the current "instance" of the cell shown in IB automatically.

It's annoying that IB keeps reporting Auto Layout errors unless I manually calculate the appropriate row height.

How do you guys handle this issue? Is there some kind of best practice, or trick?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter Actual row height in Interface builder. [Read this.](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see where your link refers to my question? To reiterate, I don't get why I have to calculate the actual row height manually in IB, even though IB obviously knows it already (since it generates an error for every wrong value).